# How can I make this aggregation query fast for my needs?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

## Describing the scenario

I have this table called `event` defined in PostgresSQL that, **among some not relevant ones**, basically has 5 columns:

- `id` (*integer*): primary key of the table
- `date` (*timestamp*): date when the event occurred
- `fk_type` (*integer*): foreign key to the type of the event (eg. Sports, Charity...)
- `fk_city` (*integer*): foreign key to the city of the event
- `status` (*varchar*): status of the event (eg. Canceled, Closed, Confirmed, etc)

There are 4 indexes defined for this table:

- *event_pkey*, for column `id`
- *ix_event_fk_type*, for column `fk_type`
- *ix_event_fk_city*, for column `fk_city`
- *ix_event_date*, for column `date`

I have this query that combines each event `e1` to the event `e2` that happened immediately after `e1`, from the same type and city of `e1`. Given a certain `fk_type` (eg. 0), the objective is to get the difference between the dates of `e2` and `e1` and determine whether it took too long (30 days or more) for `e2` to happen. If there is no `e2` after `e1`, `e1` is combined with null (hence the left join), and for this case, the default for the "took too long" is *true*.

```sql
select 
    e1.id as e1_id, 
    e1.date as e1_date, 
    min(e2.date) as next_event_date,
    min(e2.date) - e1.date as date_diff,
    case 
        when min(e2.date) - e1.date is not null then min(e2.date) - e1.date >= interval '30 days'
        else true
    end took_too_long
from event e1
left join event e2 on e2.date > e1.date 
    and e2.fk_type = e1.fk_type
    and e2.fk_city = e1.fk_city 
where e1.fk_type = 0
group by e1.id, e1.date
```

This query executes successfully, with the following execution plan:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1000.72..129436.66 rows=78930 width=37)
  Group Key: e1.id
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.72..126871.43 rows=78930 width=20)
        Workers Planned: 1
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=0.71..116991.80 rows=78930 width=20)
              Group Key: e1.id
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..29119.91 rows=17416518 width=20)
                    ->  Parallel Index Scan using ix_event_id on event e1  (cost=0.42..7456.53 rows=46429 width=20)
                          Filter: (fk_type = 0)
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_event_fk_city on event e2  (cost=0.29..0.46 rows=1 width=16)
                          Index Cond: (fk_city = e1.fk_city)
                          Filter: ((fk_type = 0) AND (date > e1.date) AND (fk_type = e1.fk_type))
```

## The problem

However, the issue is, if I try to add some other filters, say I don't want to consider events with status "*Canceled*" or "*Closed*" for this calculation, and show only events that happened in 2022 (`event.date >= '2022-01-01' and event.date < '2023-01-01'`), the query just breaks, taking forever to execute.

```sql
select 
    e1.id as e1_id, 
    e1.date as e1_date, 
    min(e2.date) as next_event_date,
    min(e2.date) - e1.date as date_diff,
    case 
        when min(e2.date) - e1.date is not null then min(e2.date) - e1.date >= interval '30 days'
        else true
    end took_too_long
from event e1
left join event e2 on e2.date > e1.date 
    and e2.fk_type = e1.fk_type
    and e2.fk_city = e1.fk_city
    and (e2.status not in ('CANCELED', 'CLOSED') or e2.status is null)
    and e2.date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
where
    (e1.status not in ('CANCELED', 'CLOSED') or e1.status is null) 
    and e1.date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and e1.date < '2023-01-01 00:00:00' 
    and e1.fk_type = 0
group by e1.id, e1.date
```

The execution plan is quite different as well. Instead of using `GroupAggregate`, the optimizer chose to use `HashAggregate`.

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=48403.48..53704.04 rows=35936 width=37)
  Group Key: e1.id
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=48403.48..52536.12 rows=35936 width=20)
        Workers Planned: 1
        ->  Sort  (cost=47403.47..47493.31 rows=35936 width=20)
              Sort Key: e1.id
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=44324.98..44684.34 rows=35936 width=20)
                    Group Key: e1.id
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..15104.27 rows=5844143 width=20)
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on event e1  (cost=0.00..2670.71 rows=21139 width=20)
                                Filter: ((((status)::text <> ALL ('{CANCELED,CLOSED}'::text[])) OR (status IS NULL)) AND (date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2023-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (fk_type = 0))
                          ->  Index Scan using ix_event_fk_city on event e2  (cost=0.29..0.58 rows=1 width=16)
                                Index Cond: (fk_city = e1.fk_city)
                                Filter: ((((status)::text <> ALL ('{CANCELED,CLOSED}'::text[])) OR (status IS NULL)) AND (date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (fk_type = 0) AND (date > e1.date) AND (fk_type = e1.fk_type))
```

The option for the `HashAggregate` seems to be the problem, since if I deactivate the `HashAggregate` from my database manually with `SET enable_hashagg = off;`, the query is executed normally without issues.

**The questions are:** Why is this happening? How can I induce Postrgres to use `GroupAggregate` instead of `HashAggregate` for my query to work properly, **without having to manually deactivate** `HashAggregate`? Is there some optimization I am missing that I can do to improve the query?

## Important things to know that I noted

If I remove some of the filter options that I set in the query, everything seems to go back to normal. For example, if I remove one of the status from the `not in ('CANCELED', 'CLOSED')` filter (say '*Closed*'), the execution is successful.

```sql
select 
    e1.id as e1_id, 
    e1.date as e1_date, 
    min(e2.date) as next_event_date,
    min(e2.date) - e1.date as date_diff,
    case 
        when min(e2.date) - e1.date is not null then min(e2.date) - e1.date >= interval '30 days'
        else true
    end took_too_long
from event e1
left join event e2 on e2.date > e1.date 
    and e2.fk_type = e1.fk_type
    and e2.fk_city = e1.fk_city
    and (e2.status not in ('CANCELED') or e2.status is null)
    and e2.date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
where
    (e1.status not in ('CANCELED') or e1.status is null) 
    and e1.date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and e1.date < '2023-01-01 00:00:00' 
    and e1.fk_type = 0
group by e1.id, e1.date
```

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1000.72..69924.89 rows=42348 width=37)
  Group Key: e1.id
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.72..68548.58 rows=42348 width=20)
        Workers Planned: 1
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=0.71..62784.42 rows=42348 width=20)
              Group Key: e1.id
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..21782.65 rows=8115659 width=20)
                    ->  Parallel Index Scan using ix_event_id on event e1  (cost=0.42..7868.54 rows=24911 width=20)
                          Filter: ((((status)::text <> 'CANCELED'::text) OR (status IS NULL)) AND (date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2023-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (fk_type = 0))
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_event_fk_city on event e2  (cost=0.29..0.55 rows=1 width=16)
                          Index Cond: (fk_city = e1.fk_city)
                          Filter: ((((status)::text <> 'CANCELED'::text) OR (status IS NULL)) AND (date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (fk_type = 0) AND (date > e1.date) AND (fk_type = e1.fk_type))
```

The same behavior happens if I remove:

1. The whole `status` filtering;
2. The whole `date` filtering ("from date" and "to date";
3. Only the "to date" piece from the `date` filtering;
4. The `fk_type` filtering.

According to my needs, this query has to work even if I specify 20 status options to filter, for instance.

## Additional info

1. `event` table has exactly 93453 rows/occurrences;
2. PostgreSQL version: *PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit*

Comment: If the sequential scan is more expensive than the index scan, PostgreSQL must estimate the index scan too expensive, because they are estimated to be almost equally expensive. Perhaps you should lower `random_page_cost` to tell PostgreSQL that random I/O is fast on your machine, or you should raise `effective_cache_size` to tell PostgreSQL that there is enough RAM to keep the index cached. The `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output that you didn't show us will suggest which of the two applies.

Comment: A single index that covers fk_city, fk_type, date and maybe status as well, could help as well. By the way, for performance issues always use EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) to get the result from the execution of the plan. A plan is just a plan and usually doesn't show you the problems you might face.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe @FrankHeikens I am sorry, I am pretty new to SQL and did not know you could use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. However, I tried to execute it in order to add this information to the question, but it did not work. It just takes forever to execute the command, failing to enable this information retrieval.

Comment: Make sure that there is no lock blocking the query. Have you tried to adjust the parameters? First, try it with `SET` on the command like, like `SET random_page_cost = 1.1;`.

Comment: You describe two queries that finish, you should be able to show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for those two.

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function to avoid the `LEFT JOIN` projection.

Start with this, and your `WHERE` criteria should have little to no impact on the runtime of the wide-open query:

```
select id, date, fk_type, fk_city,
       lead(date) over w as next_event_date,
       lead(date) over w - date as date_diff,
       coalesce(
         date + interval '30 days' <= lead(date) over w, 
         true
       ) as took_too_long
  from event
window w as (partition by fk_type, fk_city order by date);
```

Comment: Based on some early tests I've made, this might actually be very helpful! However, there is still one problem left to address: if you take a closer look to the original problematic query, in case I wish to return events from 2022, I have to filter `e1` between ['2022-01-01', '2023-01-01) and `e2` only above 2022-01-01. This happens in order to allow the calculation of the `date_diff` for a late 2022 `e1` event that had the bad fortune to have its next event `e2` only in 2023, avoinding left joining it with null wrongly. How can I ensure this behavior using your suggestion?

Comment: @LuizWillner  Wrap the query in a CTE and then filter on the date.  Try the query against your data to see the plan and whether it runs fast enough for you before trying to optimize it.  Eliminating the self-left-join should speed things up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried, you should `SET enable_hashagg = off;`

The reason why the query fails when you add the status filtering could be because the `HashAggregate` operator could not handle NULL values in the GROUP BY clause.

When you add the status filtering, the `HashAggregate` operator might have to create a hash table for each possible combination of values for the `status` column. This might lead to a very large hash table, which can cause the query to run out of memory.

The `GroupAggregate` operator, on the other hand, can handle NULL values in the GROUP BY clause. When you use the `GroupAggregate` operator, PostgreSQL would first sort the rows by the values in the GROUP BY clause. Then, it would iterate over the sorted rows and aggregate the rows that have the same values in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the `GroupAggregate` operator does not have to create a hash table, which might prevent the query from running out of memory.

To force PostgreSQL to use the `GroupAggregate` operator, you can set the `enable_hashagg` parameter to `off`. This will tell PostgreSQL to never use the `HashAggregate` operator, even if it would be more efficient to do so.

Few other points to think around:

- Use the `DISTINCT` keyword to remove duplicate rows from the results.
- Try adjusting the configuration parameter `work_mem` to allocate more memory for sorting operations, which can improve the performance of the query

```sql
SET work_mem = '64MB'; -- Adjust the value according to your available memory
```

Comment: Your distinction between `HashAggregate` and `GroupAggregate` is pretty helpful, but as I stated in the question, I don't wish to turn off `enable_hashagg`, since it might certainly be useful for other queries in the future. I wish I knew a way to write this query so it could only **induce** PostgreSQL to execute it using `GroupAggregate` instead of `HashAggregate`. Or maybe find another query that would be more adequate.